# It seems that IIS missing recorded many requests log in IIS7 log file?

Tags: iis, iis-7

For some reason, I need to check the request log of my website in IIS7 log file. After I open the log file like 'u_ex170816.log', and I found IIS recorded the requests log at a.m. completely, however after 14:00 it recorded only a little requests log util 23:59:59. I am sure that the count of requests after 14:00 is as many as a.m.. Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All entries in IIS logs are UTC time, so if your server runs in a different time zone, you have to calculate the local time by adding/subtracting the UTC time offset.

Recent requests are buffered in memory and only written out to the file logs after a while, so you may not see that latest requests in the file.

Comment: Thank you Peter very much! Yes, it is because of UTC time indeed!